# ASP.NET websites are compiled but with more HTML markup generated!

Tags: asp.net

Everytime I view the source of ASP.NET website I found alot alot of HTML markup generated. I even tried Visual web Developer and design a simple page and then do the same thing with PHP and I found ASP.NET generates more HTML!

Now, how can ASP.NET be faster if it is generating HTML in this way!

Comment: do you have an example to compare and show what you talking about in practice ? what is the extra html code that you see and its not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Template generation is a very SMALL cost compared to other things that are going on in a web request. ASP.NET offers a lot more than a straight up PHP page (Session/State management etc) and injects additional markup into the response to help with this.

However, your question in general isn't really a question, if you were to take sometime to understand the difference between a web framework and a language.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET controls generate extra markup in exchange for "easing" development